# Random Variables: Expected Values and Values computed from a data

Tags: soft-question, notation

Given a random variable $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have $E[X]$, which is called `expected value` of the random variable.

I have one random variable $X$, and I have some smaple points on the space $\Omega$. I computed the average of $X$ over these sample points, which is closed
to the expected value $E[X]$.

I would like to know how people call this value, which is computed from data.

Comment: I think "average of X over sample points" is probably a pretty good name.

Comment: "Sample mean" is a common term in English.

Comment: "Observed sample mean" to be pedantic.   The "sample mean" is in fact a random variable $X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n.$   Arithmetic mean is also OK.